# Is there a word for the particular usage of the curly brace, or a shape like it, to indicate part of a diagram?

Tags: terminology, measurement, glyphs, diagram, character

Or for measurements.

Consider the green things in this image:
[image: Labels indicating a rat and the dimensions and species thereof]

Referred here from the English SE: [english.stackexchange.com/posts/365966](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/365966)

Comment: Could they be used because they resemble [calipers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers)?

Comment: That makes sense to me! I am pretty sure I have seen these squiggles on images on the Internet of some old documents, but calipers are also pretty old.

Answer (score 1):

They are Brackets, more specific Curly Brackets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets

But the usage of thoose as a measurements is wrong. Theese are the ones that could be used.

[image]

(But I am not sure what is the name in english, so probably someone can help) Dimension lines or something?

Probably a proper usage on a diagram could be this one:

[image]

Comment: *But the usage of thoose as a measurements is wrong.* – Says who?